# parsing a specific JSON data format

Tags: java, android, json

i have this small problem,i am making a android application n use a .php file to call java script file that returns me a JSON output..now my problem is the output is in a valid JSON format, now i am confused as to how to parse the values.
the output is

> ["15.493511","73.818659"]

where the 1st value is the latitude value and the 2nd being longitude value..
what i want to do is parse this is on fetching this value in the asynctask i want to split these values ans assign them to variables. any idea how i could do this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like below,

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
        {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String data="["15.493511","73.818659"]"; // Assuming that it is your static data
                try {
                JSONArray myArray=new JSONArray(data);

                         String lattitude=myArray.getString(0);
                         String longitudetude=myArray.getString(1);

                          }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //update your UI or do your task;
                }

            }

        }
```

And execute the `AsyncTask` like following,

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

well its a json array

```
<?php

$val = '["15.493511","73.818659"]';
$arrVal = json_decode($val, true);

print_r($arrVal);

$latitude = $arrVal[0];
$longitude = $arrVal[1]
```

This will output:

```
array(15.493511, 73.818659);
```

Answer (score 1):

as you said `i want to do is parse this is on fetching this value in the asynctask` means you need to parse the `json` data in android application.

```
JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(result); //result is the json data you received
String lat = jObject.getString(0);
String long = jObject.getString(1);
```

**updated** the answer as suggested by [spring-breaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1665507/spring-breaker)

Comment: As you can see from the OP's question, the JSON data is  a `JsonArray` not a `JsonObject` as you have answered.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting JSON Array.
So your code can be something like this..

```
String latitude=jsonarray.getString(0);
String longitude=jsonarray.getString(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
            JSONArray j = new JSONArray("ur value");

            for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(j.get(i));
            }
```